# How to sort based on ordering

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

Lets say I have items

```
items : [{id:1,...}, {id:2,...}, {id:3,...}]
```

and have **ordering : [2, 3, 1]** to get an enumerable

```
items : [{id:2,...}, {id:3,...}, {id:1,...}]
```

I expect it to be something in the lines of

```
items.Select(o => new {key = ordering[i++], value = o})
     .OrderBy(k => k.key)
     .Select(o => o.value)
```

but is there a cleaner solution?

---

Following I have verified that work (HimBromBeere, Domysee, qxg)

```
var expectedOrder = ordering.Select(x => result.First(o => o.Id == x));
var expectedOrder = result.OrderBy(item => Array.FindIndex(ordering,i => i == item.Id));
var expectedOrder = result.OrderBy(item => ordering.ToList().FindIndex(i => i == item.Id));
var expectedOrder = 
  from o in ordering
  join i in result 
    on o equals i.Id
  select i;
```

---

Fwi, this was for verification test:

```
    [Test]
    [TestCase(1, 2, 3)]
    [TestCase(1, 3, 2)]
    [TestCase(2, 1, 3)]
    [TestCase(2, 3, 1)]
    [TestCase(3, 1, 2)]
    public void Test_Should_Fail_If_GetMessages_Does_Not_Return_Sorted_By_Sent_Then_By_Id_Result(params int[] ordering)
    {
        var questions = GetQuestionsData();                     
        Mock.Get(_questionService)
            .Setup(o => o.GetQuestions())
            .Returns(questions);
        var result = _mailboxService.GetMessages();    
        var expectedOrder = ordering.Select(x => result.First(o => o.Id == x));

        // Act
        Action sortOrder = () => expectedOrder.Should()
            .BeInDescendingOrder(o => o.Sent)
            .And.BeInDescendingOrder(o => o.Id);

        // Assert
        sortOrder.ShouldThrow<AssertionException>();
    }
```

Comment: Might be better to use a join to make the code more readable. Also might be a bit safer since the i++ is no longer needed.

Comment: How clean do you want? Current solution is not bad.

Comment: Just to be clear, is `ordering` a list of 1 based indexes or a list of ids in the order you want them?  Because you're getting a bunch of answers that are assuming its a list of the ids (which matches up with the example), but you're current code isn't actually using the id to lookup a value in the `ordering`.

Comment: Maybe you could give an example where the ids are not in accenting order to begin with and then show us how you would want that ordered.

Comment: You could represent your `ordering` array in a more efficient way or re-order it to that representation (look at my answer for more info).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this I guess:

```
var result = ordering.Select(x => items.First(y => y.id == x.id));
```

Working example:

```
var items = new[] { new { id = 1, name = "1" }, new { id = 2, name = "2" }, new { id = 3, name = "3" }, new { id = 4, name = "4" } };
var result = new[] { 2, 3, 1 }.Select(x => items.First(y => y.id == x));
```

This also filters those `items` out, whose index is not contained in `ordering`.

Comment: The OP isn't currently using the `id` to lookup the order value in `ordering`.  The use of `i++` indicates that the `ordering` is a list of indexes, not ids.  The example just happens to match up with it being a list of ids.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the overload of `Select` that gives you the index instead

```
items.Select((o,i) => new {key = ordering[i+1], value = o})
     .OrderBy(k => k.key)
     .Select(o => o.value);
```

This will be better because it eliminates the captured `i` variable in your example.

Answer (score 3):

If your IDs are consecutive you can rearrange the order array to contain for each index - the position the ID with the same index in the result array. This can be done like that:

```
int[] order = new[] {2, 3, 1};

order = Enumerable.Range(1, order.Length)
    .OrderBy(x => order[x - 1])
    .ToArray();

//Now order = { 3, 1, 2 } which are the one-based indices of each position in the original order array.
```

Now you can just order your `Enumerable` using that result array:

```
items = items.OrderBy(x => order[x.Id - 1]);
```

Note that if you would represent your order array this way in first place, the first `Linq` would be unnecessary, and this way ***you have no redundant iterations or sub-`Linq`s***:

```
int[] order = new[] {3, 1, 2}; //1 is third, 2 is first, 3 is second.

items = items.OrderBy(x => order[x.Id - 1]);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `ordering` is a `List`, you can do that:

```
items.OrderBy(item => ordering.FindIndex(i => i == item.id))
```

Comment: While the ids do match up that way I am guessing that `ordering` is actually a list of indexes and not ids.

Comment: @juharr oh well, in that case my solution would be wrong. Lets see if OP clarifies that.

Answer (score 2):

The only improvement is that it doesn't need order again or new object, but essentially is the same as original code.

```
var query = from o in ordering
            join i in items
                on o equals i.Id
            select i;
```