# Get new indices of items in a collection after sorting using LINQ

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, list, sorting

I want to sort a list (or array) in C# and want to save the new indexes for each of the items in the unsorted list. I.e.:

```
A = 2 3 1

sorted(A) = 1 2 3

indexes = 1 2 0 <-- This is what I need
```

I read on Stack overflow that LINQ is particularly useful, but I cannot find how to do this specifically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort based on ordering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34223684/how-to-sort-based-on-ordering)

Comment: Indexes shouldn't be as `2 0 1`?

Comment: Did you try iterating with foreach in combination with *.indexOf()*?

Comment: For the record, this is usually called a ranking function. `2` has rank 1, `3` has rank 2 and `1` has rank 0

Answer (score 23):

### Note:

I made a terrible mistake of misreading OP's question (and embarrassed this received so many upvotes). I wished (ideally) OP accepts one of the other answers as correct. To do justice to the upvoters and in spirit of SO, I will amend this answer to make it correct.

---

One could carry two extension methods, one for old indices and one for new indices (which is what OP wants).

```
public static IEnumerable<int> OldIndicesIfSorted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return source
        .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
        .OrderBy(a => a.item)
        .Select(a => a.index);
}

public static IEnumerable<int> NewIndicesIfSorted<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source) where T : IComparable<T>
{
    return source
        .OldIndicesIfSorted()
        .Select((oldIndex, index) => new { oldIndex, index })
        .OrderBy(a => a.oldIndex)
        .Select(a => a.index);
}
```

Call it like,

```
//A = [2, 3, 1];
A.NewIndicesIfSorted(); // should print [1, 2, 0]
```

The two methods are lazy, but `NewIndicesIfSorted` should ideally be written according to [Matthew Watson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35603487/661933)'s answer which is simply more efficient. The plus side of both mine and Mat's answer is that is handles duplicate entries well.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I dont get the compile error part. No this should give, [2, 0, 1] just like your answer. May be you mistyped something?

Comment: Oh I probably did. :) `A` instead of `a`. Yep it works fine. Sorry!

Comment: But doesn't OP want [1, 2, 0] (*...save the **new indexes** for each of the items..."*)

Comment: I _still_ don't understand how index of `3` should be `0` o.O

Comment: @SonerGönül The indices show where in the sorted array the original items ended up. So the original item at index 0 (which was the value 2) ended up at index 1. The original item at index 1 (which was the value 3) ended up at index 2. The original item at index 2 (which was the value 1) ended up at index 0. Hence: `1, 2, 0`

Comment: Ironic in a way that OrderBy works internally by producing an array of resorted indices, and then enumerating through them. (for one thing, it's cheaper to swap two indices than two large value type elements).

Comment: @MatthewWatson If you say so :)

Comment: @SonerGönül: Think of it like this: `sortedList[indexList[i]] == originalList[i]` has to be true for every `i`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Thanks for correction, I can't believe I got so many votes compared to other right answers. Been a bit busy to give it a second look.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this with a LINQ select:

```
var a =new [] {2,3,1};

var sorted = a.OrderBy (x => x).ToList();
var indexes = a.Select (x => sorted.IndexOf(x));
```

If this is a huge list rather than this simple one it might be a little inefficient but does return what you are expecting.

Comment: @downvoter: Can you describe what is wrong with this answer? Because as far as I can see, it is correct. It produces the correct answer of 1 2 0 as required by the OP.

Comment: @MatthewWatson It must have been my lack of a space after the equals on line 1. Ill go sit in a corner and think about what I have done now :(

Comment: I'm not @downvoter, but I would guess this was downvoted because the `IndexOf` solution is relatively inefficient compared with the `Select((item, index) => ...` solution.

Comment: @andrew.caunce I didnt downvote, but just for everyone's caution, your method may not work as intended in case of duplicates.

Answer (score 4):

One way to do this is as follows:

```
int[] a = {2, 3, 1};
int[] b = Enumerable.Range(0, a.Length).ToArray();
int[] c = new int[a.Length];

Array.Sort(a, b);

for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i)
    c[b[i]] = i;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c)); // Prints 1, 2, 0
```

It uses the overload of `Array.Sort()` which sorts one array using the values from a different array.

I think this is fairly efficient: It uses a O(N log(N)) sort and an O(N) remapping. (The other correct solutions are O(N log(N)) plus O(N^2))

It only works with arrays, however (because there is no equivalent of `Array.Sort()` for List).

An alternative using Linq (and effectively an amendment to @nawfal's answer):

```
int[] a = {2, 3, 1};

var b = a
    .Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
    .OrderBy(x => x.item)
    .Select(x => x.index)
    .ToArray();

int[] c = new int[b.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i)
    c[b[i]] = i;

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", c)); // Prints 1, 2, 0
```

The crucial thing here is the additional mapping step in both approaches:

```
int[] c = new int[b.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; ++i)
    c[b[i]] = i;
```

This is effectively a reverse-lookup mapping.

Comment: Interessant way to do this but using Enumerable.Range doesn't seem to be the clearest and most straightforward to achieve it

Comment: @AFract Well you just need a list of indices to sort alongside the keys, and `Enumerable.Range()` is pretty much the easiest way I know of to generate that.

Comment: @downvoter: Can you describe what is wrong with this answer? Because as far as I can see, it is correct. It produces the correct answer of `1 2 0` as required by the OP.

Comment: (Please note despite my remark above, I'm not the downvoter, and my comment is not anymore relevant since you have edited your answer)

Comment: @AFract I feel sure that you would have explained why you were downvoting if it was you. :) Anyway, I don't mind being downvoted at all, it's just that I'd like to know why, so things can be improved.

Comment: I'm of course one of the upvoters. And really wondering why the good correct answers are downvoted and at the same time the trivial and obviously incorrect one is highly upvoted. Quite disappointing.

Comment: This should ideally be the accepted answer. Best one here. I liked your original answer too which uses `Array.Sort` twice. I now understand why you changed it. I didnt want to shamelessly copy yours, so I wrote one myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Another working solution:

```
var input = new List<int> { 2, 3, 1 };
var result = input.Select(x => input.OrderBy(n => n).ToList().IndexOf(x));

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(" ", result));  // 1 2 0
```

Comment: This is same as andrew's answer, apparently less performant. Take the orderby outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

While reading other answers I got a little confused about which `indexes` order you want exactly, but here's solution if you want them to in order `1 2 0` as you posted in your question. Try this:

```
var A = new int[] { 2, 3, 1 };
var indexes = new int [A.Length];

var sorted = A.OrderBy(n => n)
              .Select((n, i) => 
                      { 
                          indexes[Array.IndexOf(A, n)] = i;

                          return n; 
                      })
              .ToArray();
```

Comment: Wouldn't work if you have duplicate entries. Also note, not many like sideeffects in LINQ query like this.